# it's print null in console when I run a program in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

`

```
package Stuff;

public class Student{
private String name;
private int age;

public Student(String studentName,int studentAge){
    studentName = name;
    studentAge = age;
}

public void printName(){
    System.out.println(name);
}

public void printAge(){
    System.out.println(age);
    }

public void printInfo(){
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(age);
}

public static void main(String[] arg0){
    Student  student1;
    student1 = new Student("ragaey",22);

    student1.printInfo();

}

}
```

`
I Don't Know where is the wrong in code the console print me (null) when i request student1.printName() and 0 When i request Student.printAge()

Comment: The assignments in your constructor are the wrong way round.

Comment: `this.name = studentName` would be much much better.

Comment: You are amazing my wrong is I Reversed it should like what you told me Thanks Man

Comment: @RagaeyM.Ragaa Although your question is answered, I highly recommend you look at my answer to understand the problem, rather than just copy-pasting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the variables in the constructor in wrong way. The correct way will be:

```
public Student(String studentName,int studentAge){
    name = studentName;
    age = studentAge;
}
```

If you auto-generate the constructors then it will look like this, which is more common convention:

```
public Student(String name,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable assignments in the constructor are the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the initialization part `studentname = name and studentage = age` the right way of initialization is given down

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private int age;

public Student(String studentName,int studentAge){
    name = studentName;
    age = studentAge;
}

public void printName(){
    System.out.println(name);
}

public void printAge(){
    System.out.println(age);
    }

public void printInfo(){
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(age);
}

public static void main(String[] arg0){
    Student  student1;
    student1 = new Student("ragaey",22);

    student1.printInfo();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor should be like

```
public Student(String studentName,int studentAge){
    this.name = studentName;
    this.age = studentAge;
}
```

Comment: It's really not helping the OP. You've unnecessarily added the `this` keyword, which would only confuse the OP further.

Comment: I guess i am used to it. it is just current object instance reference. If there is something that confuse , i would like to learn also

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you have a look at [this article on associativity in Java](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

Basically, when you assign a value to a variable using the `=` operator, the statement is carried out from right to left. Hence, the outcome of the expression on the Right Hand Side is assigned to the variable on the Left Hand Side.

Hence, `int a = 5+5` means that the outcome of `5+5` is stored in variable `a`. This is also why `studentName = name` assigns the value of `name` (which is the default value of the String type - `null`) to `studentName`.

It is also important to note that `null` is a keyword in Java, and if you print null like this:

```
System.out.println(null)
```

A Syntax Error will be thrown (which is for a different reason).

**EDIT -** At the time of typing this out, there was only one answer, and not explanatory in any way. Now, I see there are more. Although the other answers may tell you what to do, I figured that this answer would tell you **how to think** in Java, so that you make no such mistakes again.

Comment: @RagaeyM.Ragaa Anytime. And please remember to find the answer that helps you to understand the situation better, rather than the one that just tells you *what to do* :)

Comment: @RagaeyM.Ragaa Also, you seem to have marked the shortest answer as helpful. Please remember that you can only mark one answer as helpful, so mark the most appropriate answer as such, so that others can refer it, if not mine.